# Number of permutations of m objects taken out of n objects where an object can repeat any number of times.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I'm given $n$ distinct objects. In how many ways can we select and permute $m$ objects out of those $n$ objects. $n$ may be less than $m$ and any object can appear any number of times.
For example:

$n=2$ (Objects are say $1$ and $2$)

$m=3$

Then required number of permutations are: $8 [ (1,1,1) (2,2,2) (1,2,2) (2,1,2) (2,2,1) (1,1,2) (1,2,1) (2,1,1) ]$

How can I approach this problem.

Comment: Just $n^m$. In your case, it would be $2^3 = 8$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is indeed $n^m$. A simple example would be a binary sequence: if we have an alphabet $\{0,1 \}$, how many unique ways of writing a string length $n$? It's $2^n$ of course, because you have an 'infinite' supply of 0- and 1-bits.